# Extracting a substring from XML element

Tags: python, rss, feedparser, pubmed

I am trying to extract the 'Abstract' substring from the 'Description' elements of an XML RSS feed. Code snippet:

```
import feedparser

rss = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/erss.cgi?rss_guid=1RGmO3jHeXUu8o2CWPinET6JLLik93hwR2IAJ5mU-YzoPeX1-O'
feed = feedparser.parse(rss)

for post in feed.entries:
   print (post.description)
```

The string I want from the first item is embedded in description between `<p>Abstract<br/> ...... <br/>`:

```
The recent development of electronic logbooks with secure off-device data storage provides a rich resource for research. We present the largest analysis of anaesthetic logbooks to date, with data from 494,235 cases logged by 964 anaesthetists over a 4-year period. Our analysis describes and compares the annual case-load and supervision levels of different grades of anaesthetists across the UK and Republic of Ireland. We calculated the number of cases undertaken per year by grade (median (IQR [range]) core trainees = 388 (252-512 [52-1204]); specialist trainees = 344 (228-480 [52-1144]); and consultants = 328 (204-500 [52-1316]). Overall, the proportion of cases undertaken with direct consultant supervision was 56.7% and 41.6% for core trainees and specialist trainees, respectively. The proportion of supervised cases reduced out-of-hours, for both core trainees (day 93.5%, evening 86.3%, night 78.6%) and specialist trainees (day 81.0%, evening 67.7%, night 56.4%)
```

I'm not sure how to strip everything else away from the description apart from the abstract. I'm guessing I use a regex search, I've tried answers from similar substring questions and couldn't get it to work, possibly because of the html tags.

Much appreciated

Comment: Your question seems vague or is missing essential details/code. Please post the code you are currently using and the error/issue that you have with it. Please look over [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing PubMed feed results you could use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# find all p(aragraph) tags which have "Abstract" in their text
def find_abstract(tag):
    return tag.name == 'p' and tag.text.startswith('Abstract')

soup = BeautifulSoup(post.description)

# find the abstract
result = soup.find(find_abstract)

# format the text: keep everything but the first line
abstract = '\n'.join(result.text.splitlines()[1:]).strip()
print(abstract)
```